# How to get all user attributes in the response after successful signin using AWS Amplify and Cognito Userpool

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I m using AWS Cognito userpool to authenticate the users of my website.
User has to simply enter userName (emailId in my case), password to login to the app.
After successful login, I can see bellow attributes in the repose.

```
{
    "UserAttributes":[
        {"Name":"sub","Value":"XYZ"},
        {"Name":"email_verified","Value":"true"},
        {"Name":"email","Value":"someone@example.com"}
    ],
    "Username":"someone@example.com"
}
```

Now i have added a new attribute to the user and expecting that attribute to be returned in the response after signin, but unfortunately not getting that attribute.

Can someone help me in understanding how to get all the attributes of the user (including the custom attributes which i have added) after signin. I m kind of new to this AWS cognito.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In your user pool settings, select App Clients and click on Show Details under your app client to expand it.
At the very bottom, click on "Set attribute read and write permissions". Now you can select whatever attributes you want to show up in your ID Token. Whatever is under Readable attributes will be added to your token which you can then decode.

Note that this is only added to ID token and not Access Token.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

call `fetchUserAttributes` after sign in as mentioned in this [doc](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/user-attributes/q/platform/android)

```
    Amplify.Auth.fetchUserAttributes(
    attributes -> Log.i("AuthDemo", "User attributes = " + attributes.toString()),
    error -> Log.e("AuthDemo", "Failed to fetch user attributes.", error)
);
```